# Visual Studio misbehaving

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

This may seem like a small problem, but it is beginning to infuriate me to the point where I cannot bare to open Visual Studio.

The problem:

A while ago I create a Website in VS. I named it, "TestWebsite". A week later I deleted it, both from the Websites folder, the Projects folder and also the Backup folder.

I also deleted it from the VS Start page recent items list, and also from the Jumplist for VS on the Taskbar.

I then created a new website called "TestWebsite" (same name). But when VS finished creating the new website, it was not called "TestWebsite". VS renamed it to "TestWebsite (1)". So I deleted it, and all other traces of this name from my system.

I then created a new website called "TestWebsite" (same name), and again, it renamed it to "TestWebsite (2)".

You see what's going on here?

How do I stop this? It happens no matter what I create. Project/Website/Class Library. It always renames things and it's really aggrivating me. I need it to stop.

Please help.

Comment: search your registry?

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one. I think that's the only thing I haven't done.

Comment: Hopefully I'll be done by next week. There's 10's of thousands of entried in there. WTF.

Comment: @Mordachai, thank you! The solution seems to be to delete everything and search the registry and get rid of relevant items in MRUList entries.

Comment: Bummer.  Undocumented stuff like this can drive you nuts.  GL!

Comment: ;-( Why do these simple things happen so often? Why is it so hard to do something so simple now? Why can't they just leave things be. It used to work great but now they're screwing everything up! My heart is sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Delete relevant entries in the applicationhost.config file (which is located in the Drive:\Users\User\Documents\IISExpress\config folder)
2. Search the Registry (Microsoft > Visual Studio 12 > MRUList), and delete relevant entries;
3. Delete the Projects and Websites in their respective folders (but first back them up to a different location if necessary);
4. Open the IIS folder, delete files directly related to your current project;
5. Clear JumpList and Recent Projects history (probably not necessary, but makes things look cleaner).

Answer (score 2):

When VS creates a website using IIS Express, the website is also added to the applicationhost.config file for IIS Express (under Documents\IISExpress\config).  The names for these IIS Express hosted websites need to be unique, which is why VS adds the (n) modifier to the name.

To reuse the same exact name, you can clear out the applicationhost.config sites and then create the project.